# How can I compute E(X²)?

Tags: probability

• Let X be a random variable with possible values {−2, 0, 2} and such that P (X = 0) = 0.2. Compute E(X²).
How can I compute the value of E(X²) without knowing the probabilities P(X=-2) and P(X=2)?

Comment: The first step is to try. What have you tried? Writing explicitly what that expectation is, as a sum of three terms, would be a good first idea -- you may notice something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in the symmetry of the random variable. Clearly $X^2 \in \{0, 4\}$.

$P(X^2 = 0) = .2$ and $P(X^2 = 4) = P(X = 2) + P(X = -2) = 1 - .2 = .8$.

Then $E X^2 = 0 \times .2 + 4 \times .8 = 3.2.$